# RDP connection in Proxmox VM using Cloudflare Isn't working

Tags: cloudflare, rdp, proxmox, cloudflare-argo

I have really struggled with the last part in my Cloudflare Tunnel journey. I created a LXC container with cloudflared tunnel. This is to get my Windows 10 vm and Linux vm to provide me access from a public hostname

W10 VM is sitting on a PROXMOX server with a couple of Linux Servers (VM’s), Portainer and Dashboard . All the linux vm are accessible via public hostname using cloudflare Tunnel

ie.

portainer`mydomain`com - Service https 192.168.1.11:9443
dashboard`mydomain`com - Service https 192.168.1.12:8443
proxmox`mydomain`com - Service https 192.168.1.10:8006

Now, I want to connect to the Windows 10 VM (192.168.1.13) via RDP. Locally I can do this but I want to be able to connect via the Cloudflare tunnel

I have tried

w10rdp . `mydomain`. com - Service rdp 192.168.1.13:3389 but this wont connect to the w10 vm.

I spin up an XAMPP server with 80 port on windows vm and tried the same thing:
xampp.mydomain.com -> 192.168.1.13:80
And it worked. But when I tried doing that using the RDP connection running on port 3389 (Which I can also connect locally), it didn't work. I tried changing the port to something else, but still not working.

I want the cloudflare tunnel to work on windows VM for RDP connection. Only the RDP isn't working. I've tried spinning up an XAMPP server with 80 port on windows vm and tried the same thing:
xampp.mydomain.com -> 192.168.1.13:80
And it worked.